# Copy a value through column if identifiers are the same

Tags: sql, sas

I would like to copy a value if it's identifier can found more than one time. For exemple, here, I'd like to spread the "111" through all the "1" and the "222" through all the "2" in colA

```
Col A   Col B    Col C
1         111     500
1          -        -
1          -       888
2          -      555
2        222       -
2          -       -
```

After the process, i'd like to have

```
Col A   Col B    Col C
1         111     500
1         111     -
1         111     888
2         222     555
2         222     - 
2         222     -
```

I use SAS at my job but I don't care using something else. However I have 16M of entries so might be better not to export in csv and doing everything in SAS.

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe SAS is mostly relate to sql-server, so I'll use sql-server query to solve the problem.

```
select col1,max(col2) over(partition by col1) as col2,col3 from [tableName]
```

this should grant the expect output.
check [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=825ee6a4232b52fcacff45f856bdd50b)

and in SAS I think you need to use this:

```
proc sql;
select col1,max(col2) over(partition by col1) as col2,col3 from [tableName]
quit;
```

Comment: Thanks ! Unfortunatly it doesn't work in SAS. Do you know how this operation is called ? I could then search by myself how to do it in SAS.

Comment: have you use `proc sql` in SAS? I think this is needed in SAS to start using query.

Comment: Thank you so much, so I looked a bit on the internet and the over(partition by) has to be replaced by group by.

The answer in SAS code is : 

`select col1, max(col2),col3 from[tableName] 
group by col1
quit;`

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the max with `Proc MEANS` and `update` the target data set in place.

```
data have;
input A B C; datalines;
1 111 500
1  .   .
1  .  888
2  .  555
2 222  .
2  .   .
;

proc means nway noprint data=have;
  class a;
  var b;
  output max=b_max out=maxes(drop=_type_ _freq_);
run;

proc sql;
  update have 
  set b=(select b_max from maxes where maxes.a=have.a)
  where missing(b)
  ;

%let syslast = have;
```

Other ways would rewrite the entire result data set

```
* rely on Proc SQL automatic remerge feature (SAS only);

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    a,
    case when b is missing then max(b) else b end as b,

/* can also compute with coalesce */
    coalesce(b,max(b)) as b_2nd_way,

    c
  from
    have
  group by
    a;
```

or you can use DOW loop technique;

```
data want(drop=_:);
  do until (last.A);            * compute over group loop;
    set have; 
    by A; 
    _max_b = max(_max_b, b);
  end;
  do until (last.A);            * apply over group loop;
    set have; 
    by A;
    if missing(b) then b = _max_b;
    OUTPUT;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Proc SQL solution that I think meets your requirements

```
    /** Create dataset **/
data have;
    input A $2. B 4.0   C 3.0  ;
datalines;
1 111 500
1 
1     888
2     555
2 222   
2  
;
run;


proc sql;
    create table want as
        select t1.A, t2.B, t1.C
        from have as t1
        left join (select A, max(B) as B from have group by A) as t2 on t1.A = t2.A;
quit;
```